# to launch a Dialog from a Service, should I use Activity or View?

Tags: java, android

Say I'm running a service and need to pop out a dialog. As we know, it's impossible to launch a dialog directly from a service, therefor we need to launch and activity ( or view ) and then have it launch our dialog.

The dialog, as well as the activity launching it, should NOT obstruct whatever is below it, i.e. what's on screen should not turn gray and any buttons, that are outside of the dialog, should still be clickable.

Can this be achieved with using an activity or would the activity block the view under it anyway?

If so, guess I would have to use a view... since I haven't worked with views before, what would be the right way to initialize it, so that it won't obstruct whatever is under it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could have it launch as an activity using the Dialog theme:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html (see heading: Apply a theme to an Activity or application)

Although, no matter what you will probably obstruct the user in some way ;-). This method should only show a minimal dialog box instead of taking up the whole screen though

Comment: I'm using android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" to make it see-through all right, but also need it to be click-through. :)

Comment: hmm, I guess I am not sure what you mean by click-through? You would surely be able to click the activity, right?

Comment: Also, it seems like the 'Android' way would be to launch a notification, and then the user would be able to click the notification to pull up a view. Could you achieve the same thing using this pattern? The notification would not block the user in anyway

Comment: not really. imagine a service with lots of buttons, such as a keyboard, and I need to get a dialog on top of it. But the user should be able to click on buttons that belong to a service which in under the activity, which has brought up the dialog. :) hope it makes sense.

Comment: I see. Hmm, I don't know how to achieve what you are trying to achieve. Good luck!

Comment: I guess it could be somehow done with a View, i.e. a service call a veiw and the view calls a dialog. just I'm not sure, how to make that "view". :)

Answer (score 1):

> Can this be achieved with using an activity

No.

> would the activity block the view under it anyway?

Yes.

> If so, guess I would have to use a view

A view normally is hosted by an activity. A service cannot just create some random view and put it on the screen.

You can attempt to use a `Toast` with a custom `View` for a modeless "dialog", but I am uncertain if a service-constructed `View` will work with that.

Comment: nope, tried using custom toast, but seems I can't interact with it.

Comment: @Roger: Oh, sorry, didn't realize you were trying to interact with it.  What you want is impossible, sorry -- only the foreground activity can interact with the user in the way you are seeking.